# 32-bit assignments for 16-bit port addresses

Tags: assembly, io, x86

As I was digging through the original Xbox kernel's code, I noticed that sometimes when it sets up the registers for port I/O, it assigns a 32-bit value to `edx`, even though the `in` and `out` instructions only use the low 16 bits of `edx` for the port address. As an example:

```
mov     edx, 0FFFF8004h
in      ax, dx
or      ax, 1
out     dx, ax
add     edx, 1Eh
in      ax, dx
or      ax, 2
out     dx, ax
mov     edx, 0FFFF8002h
...
```

Elsewhere (such as SMBus read and write), it's inconsistent; sometimes it assigns 16-bit values to `dx`, other times 32-bit values to `edx`.

If the upper 16 bits are never used, what's the point of specifying non-zero bits for them?

Comment: I'm speculating here, but in 32-bit mode, you need an operand size prefix to move a 16-bit immediate into a register. That could possibly be slower to decode. More likely, the programmer used an integer literal, which defaults to signed 32-bit `int` on the platform. If the literal was a negative number, that would likely result in the sort of code you see.

Comment: @EOF that's what I thought too, but again, they're inconsistent - sometimes a 16-bit immediate *is* used. Also, because of the instruction encodings, the immediate is encoded as a full 32-bit integer, i.e. no sign-extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that's done as micro-optimization to avoid a non-existent hazard and/or insignificant performance penalty.

For example, the programmer may have originally wrote something like:

```
66| BA 8004     mov     dx, 8004h
66| ED          in      ax, dx
66| 83 C8 01    or      ax, 1
66| EF          out     dx, ax
66| 83 C2 1E    add     dx, 1Eh
```

He then decided to replace `add dx` with `add edx` in order to save a byte and eliminate the performance penalty for decoding the operand size prefix:

```
66| BA 8004     mov     dx, 8004h
66| ED          in      ax, dx
66| 83 C8 01    or      ax, 1
66| EF          out     dx, ax
83 C2 1E        add     edx, 1Eh
```

Then he reads this in a contemporary Intel optimization manual:

> Because Pentium II and Pentium III processors can execute code out of
>   order, the instructions need not be immediately adjacent for the stall to
>   occur. Example 2-7 also contains a partial stall.
>
> **Example 2-7 Partial Register Stall with Pentium II and Pentium III Processors**
>
> ```
> MOV AL, 8
> MOV EDX, 0x40
> MOV EDI, new_value
> ADD EDX, EAX        ; Partial stall accessing EAX
> ```

His own code now looks similar so he avoids the partial register stall by replacing the 16-bit `MOV` instruction with the 32-bit one you see in your example. (In reality I don't think `ADD` instruction will ever stall, the `IN` and `OUT` instructions should give the `MOV` instruction more than enough time to retire.)

And yes, these micro-optimizations would be pointless. Even if they do save a CPU cycle or two, the performance gain would be insignificant compared to time it takes to execute the I/O instructions. But it wouldn't be at all surprising to see a Microsoft employee doing this. I've seen dumber things than this in Microsoft code, and during the 90's at least they seemed pretty obsessed with micro-optimizations.

The inconsistency you see is also not surprising. Microsoft would have had a number of different programmers working on the Xbox kernel, and could have easily included code from Windows or other projects.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting as well. Still not sure why `0xFFFF` for the upper part, but I suppose it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Drew Any chance that this might be inline assembly? The compiler might have sign-extended a 16-bit constant.

Comment: @Drew and Ross: There is no decode penalty on the operand-size prefix in the `add` or `or`, other than code size.  `add dx, 0x1E` uses the `imm8` encoding, so the operand-size prefix doesn't change the length of the rest of the insn.  It's only `imm16` operands on ALU ops that cause length-changing-prefix stalls.  Oops, orig xbox has a PIII, which can LCP stall even on `mov` instructions, so that's what they're avoiding if decode speed for this code mattered.  `add edx, imm8` just saves one code byte, and doesn't avoid a partial-reg stall unless `in` reads the whole reg and forces a merge.

Comment: @PeterCordes Regardless of whether it was a problem or not, Intel's optimization manuals for the Pentium III did say things like "Whenever possible, avoid prefixing instructions." My theory here is the micro-optimizations were applied without consideration of the actual performance benefit on the actual hardware. For example, they could have been avoiding the penalty more explicitly documented for the Pentium: "An instruction with a 66h or 67h prefix takes one clock for prefix detection, another clock for length calculation, and another clock to enter the FIFO (three clock cycles total)."

Comment: @RossRidge: Yeah, I got your overall point.  I was just pointing out that the most dangerous potential stall was probably the LCP stall on a 16bit mov-imm.  But good point about how the old manuals were worded.  Your theory about blindly following the optimization manual even for I/O code sounds very likely.  16bit `mov` / 32bit `add` and 32bit `or` would minimize code size, which is the best bet here.  P6 partial-register stalls are way worse than on SnB (extra uop inserted), but hopefully even that huge amount of stalling wouldn't hurt.